# Apply a lambda function to a range of elements in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I understand that you can use lambda expressions similarly to LINQ queries to filter a collection or to select its elements. I was wondering if you could also call methods or apply something to the elements of a collection.

For example, if I have a class called `TrashCan` that can contain a list of `Trash` items, like this:

```cs
public class TrashCan
{
    ...
    public List<Trash> Trash { get; set; }

    public void AddTrash(Trash[] trashItems)
    {
        foreach (Trash trashItem in trashItems)
        {
            Trash.Add(trashItem);
        }
    }
}
```

If I then have a city block containing some number of trash cans, and I want to pretend that people are putting some trash in them, I would like to do something like this:

```cs
var trashCans = new List<TrashCan>() { t1, t2, t3, t4, ..., tN };
var trashItems = new List<Trash>() { bananaPeel, beerBottle, flyer, ... };

var subTrashCans = trashCans.GetRange(3, 10);
var subTrashItems = trashItems.GetRange(5, 3);

// Normal way
foreach (var trashCan in subTrashCans)
{
    trashCan.AddTrash(subTrashItems.ToArray());
}

// Lambda way?
trashCans.GetRange(3, 10).DoForEach(x => AddTrash(trashItems.GetRange(5, 3))); // Can it be done somehow?
```

Comment: There is [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netcore-3.1) method

Comment: There is no LINQ `ForEach` method out of the box. `List` has one specifically, as mentioned by @PavelAnikhouski, and you can use `Select` to mimic this behavior in some cases, as mentioned by @MindSwipe. You can also install the `MoreLinq` package, which includes `ForEach` and other additional operators on collections.

Comment: Thanks guys, I had no idea that there was a `ForEach` for lists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netcore-3.1) if you have a `List<T>`

```cs
trashCans.ForEach(x => x.AddTrash(subTrashItems.GetRange(5, 3).ToArray()));
```

But this has one flaw, we're calling `.GetRange(3, 5).ToArray()` once every iteration, while we could only call it once like so:

```cs
// Either do it right at the declaration:
var subTrashItems = trashItems.GetRange(5, 3).ToArray();
trashCans.ForEach(x => x.AddTrash(subTrashItems));

// Or create a new variable and insert it again and again
var subTrashItemArray = subTrashItems.ToArray();
trashCans.ForEach(x => x.AddTrash(subTrashItemArray));
```

---

**Short tangent about deferred execution in LINQ:**

LINQ supports something called [`deferred execution`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example), which means that your LINQ expression will only be executed once it's actually needed. This has many upsides, but one downside: it's easy to accidentally execute the same code multiple times without having to. In your example your calling `.ToArray()` in your loop, and it executes `.GetRange(3, 5)` once every loop, which is bad. Instead, call `.ToArray()` once when declaring `subTrashItems` and then you never need it again

Comment: That won't even compile because `AddTrash` returns void, and if it didn't, you've created an unneeded list.

Comment: @SeanReid is right, using `Select` doesn't work, however, `ForEach` did the trick!

Comment: @SeanReid you're correct about the Select, I didn't see that it returned a void, I fixed it in my answer

Comment: I ended up using the full statement that would satisfy my original example, which is `trashCans.GetRange(3, 10).ForEach(x => x.AddTrash(trashItems.GetRange(5, 3).ToArray()))` (didn't have to be very readable because it was for testing purposes, but I understand your concern about efficiency)

Comment: @JansthcirlU If it's only for testing it's fine, but if it's for production I'd recommend splitting out `trashItems.GetRange(5, 3).ToArray()` into a separate variable so you're not calling it once every iteration